# PhpStorm Can not run PHP Code CodeSniffer

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

Im trying to use CodeSniffer in PhpStorm.

In **settings->PHP->CLI Interpreter** 
I linked to the php.exe Im using https://windows.php.net/ but also tried it with Cygwin and XAMPP.

PhpStorm shows me the right PHP Version 7.2.5 and the php.ini

In the CodeSniffer configuration I selected the phpcs.bat
When Im clicking on Validate I just got

> Can not run PHP Code

Also added everything to the `PATH`

Did I miss something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try running the phpcs file instead of the phpcs.bat file

Comment: Then I get `Cannot run program "...\phpcs": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32-Application`

Comment: 1) Screenshots with settings please. Details matters. 2) Is you `php.exe` is system-wide discoverable? I mean -- will it show the right path if you run `where php` in terminal (outside of IDE)?

Comment: I added some screens

Comment: You are executing `phpcs.bat` -- perfect. .BAT file inside calls your `php.exe` (as it does not know anything about PhpStorm and PHP Interpreters and stuff) ... and right now it looks like `php.exe` is not actually discoverable by OS. You need to put the path to it into system `PATH` variable. That's what error message suggests me...

Comment: When Im calling `where php` it shows me the correct path to the php.exe. When im calling `php *\phpcs.bat` in cmd it will be executed without an error

Comment: Check `idea.log` for possible hints then (`Help | Show Log in Explorer`)

Comment: there are no hints. Also did a new install via pear

Answer (score 3):

You should put `phpcs.bat` and `phpcs` in your PHP folder - e.g. `d:\program\php\phpcs`. The CodeSniffer itself should reside in `d:\program\php\PEAR\PHP\CodeSniffer` - there will be a script `autoload.php` and a subfolder `src`.

Then in `Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Code Sniffer` you specify the path to `phpcs.bat` and `Validate` it.

Then in `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections` you find the node `PHP Code Sniffer validation` and enable it. After enabling it you will be able to configure it - specifically choose the coding standard.

[image]
[image]

This is my `phpcs`

```
#!D:\PROGRAM\Inet\Design\php\php.exe
<?php
/**
 * PHP_CodeSniffer detects violations of a defined coding standard.
 *
 * @author    Greg Sherwood <gsherwood@squiz.net>
 * @copyright 2006-2015 Squiz Pty Ltd (ABN 77 084 670 600)
 * @license   https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/licence.txt BSD Licence
 */

if (is_file(__DIR__.'/../autoload.php') === true) {
    include_once __DIR__.'/../autoload.php';
} else {
    include_once 'PHP/CodeSniffer/autoload.php';
}

$runner   = new PHP_CodeSniffer\Runner();
$exitCode = $runner->runPHPCS();
exit($exitCode);
```

This is my `phpcs.bat`

```
@echo off
REM PHP_CodeSniffer detects violations of a defined coding standard.
REM 
REM @author    Greg Sherwood <gsherwood@squiz.net>
REM @copyright 2006-2015 Squiz Pty Ltd (ABN 77 084 670 600)
REM @license   https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/licence.txt BSD Licence

if "%PHPBIN%" == "" set PHPBIN=D:\PROGRAM\Inet\Design\php\php.exe
if not exist "%PHPBIN%" if "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%" neq "" goto USE_PEAR_PATH
GOTO RUN
:USE_PEAR_PATH
set PHPBIN=%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%
:RUN
"%PHPBIN%" "D:\PROGRAM\Inet\Design\php\phpcs" %*
```

This is my `PEAR_ENV.reg` which I have imported into Windows Registry

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"="D:\\PROGRAM\\Inet\\Design\\php"
"PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR"="D:\\PROGRAM\\Inet\\Design\\php\\pear"
"PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR"="D:\\PROGRAM\\Inet\\Design\\php\\docs"
"PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR"="D:\\PROGRAM\\Inet\\Design\\php"
"PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR"="D:\\PROGRAM\\Inet\\Design\\php\\data"
"PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN"="D:\\PROGRAM\\Inet\\Design\\php\\php.exe"
"PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR"="Z:\\Temp\\"
```

Comment: I did it like in your description, but I cant `Validate` it

Comment: Perhaps `Validate` shows some meaningful error message?

Comment: Thank you! I installed everything new with pear and now it works. But still dont know what was wrong :)

Comment: @TedLoganHow did you install with PEAR on windows?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not a satisfying solution, but for me (on Windows 10, having installed CodeSniffer as global composer installation) it got resolved by **restarting PhpStorm**.

Comment: I reached the mouth of the rabbits hole when I found this gentle reminder to try rebooting. AND IT WORKED. Thanks!

Comment: I came where when setting up on ubuntu, with docker. After restarting it helped me to make show custom coding standard.

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody stumbles on this looking for how to set up PhpStorm tools that are installed within WSL/WSL2, [this JetBrains issue thread helped me](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-52052).

Basically, you want to set your CLI interpreter to the version of PHP within your WSL OS (for me, Ubuntu) under **Languages & Frameworks** > **PHP**. Then, under **Quality Tools**, you want to create a new configuration (the plus sign on the top-left side of the pop-up window that appears after you press the "..." button), select your CLI interpreter, and configure it from there. Be sure to use forward slashes for the path (e.g. "/home/[...]") and make it relative to the interpreter's OS (i.e. no need to start the path with "\\$wsl[...]"). After saving, you can select that Interpreter next to *Configuration* (instead of "Local") for that tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using OpenServer with PHP 7.0-64x
I only have composer and PHP in my Env. vars.

but before i tested it in console and everything was just fine
phpcs version: 3.3.2 (latest for these days)
smth like this:

> C:\OpenServer\domains\phpWorkingWithFiles\vendor\bin>phpcs
>   --standard=PSR2 C:\OpenServer\domains\phpWorkingWithFiles\classes\Recipe.php

or like this

> C:\OpenServer\domains\phpWorkingWithFiles>vendor\bin\phpcs classes/
>   --colors

had the same error I had reran the Phpstorm and it started working

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem too;then i remove phpcs which is in the same dir with phpcs.bat,and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

We also had the same problem and there was no PHP installed.

To be able to load  code sniffer you MUST have PHP installed (locally on your PC/Laptop)!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with php cli to see the error text.
In my case it was:

```
$ php /home/alex/apps/code-style/code-style/scripts/phpcs.php
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/daniel/apps/code-style/code-style/scripts/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/daniel/apps/code-style/code-style/scripts/phpcs.php on line 3
```

(I forgot to run `composer install` command in project root).

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting PC solved issue.
Tried restarting PHPStorm and relogin from Windows user, but did not work

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding PHP to Windows Environment path solved the issue.

Even though, I set the path of PHP in PHPStorm Settings -> Language & Frameworks-> PHP -> CLI Interpreter I still got this error, until I set it in Windows Environment Variables.

In my case error message was **Can not run PHP_CodeSniffer** when I tried to validate the path of `phpcs.bat`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error `Cannot run program "phpcs.phar": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32-Application` when I selected the `phpcs.phar` file in PHPStorm. My `%PATH%` included my PHP installation directory and I could run `php` from a command prompt.

The error from PHPStorm implied that it was trying to launch `phpcs.phar` as an executable, rather than passing it to PHP with `php phpcs.phar`. I fixed the issue by creating a `phpcs.bat` containing the following:

```
@php C:\absolute\path\to\phpcs.phar %1
```

I then selected my `phpcs.bat` in PHPStorm, instead of `phpcs.phar`. I was then able to validate and run the tool from within PHPStorm. The same approach worked for the other code quality tools.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the interpreter and choose the PHP version that you want to use.

[image]

Next, navigate to Quality Tools and enable PHP CS Fixer with the correct PHP Interpreter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on MacOs using MAMP with path pointing php to a custom batch file that switches the version depending on the local folder it is called from, so the default config was never going to work for me.

I edited the `<path to project>/vendor/bin/phpcs` and `<path to project>/vendor/bin/phpcbf` and swapped the top line of

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

with

```
#!/usr/bin/env <path to PHP file in MAMP>
```

Seems to validate after that